# Importing a function from another TS file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'buttonToast' of undefined
```

when I am trying to import the buttonToast from another `.ts` file in **ionic project**. heres the code which I am trying:

**firstfile.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController, ToastOptions } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class ToastProvider { 
    toast: any;
    constructor(public toastCtrl: ToastController, public toastOptions: ToastOptions) {

    }
buttonToast(toastMessage) {
    this.toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: toastMessage,
        position: 'middle',
        showCloseButton: true,
        closeButtonText: "OK",
        cssClass: "sessionToast",
    });
    this.toast.present();
    }
}
```

**secondfile.ts**

```
import { ToastProvider } from '../providers/toast/toast';
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class SignupPage {
    toastCtrl: ToastProvider
        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad secondPage');
    }


    alertCtrl(){
        this.toastCtrl.buttonToast("Please sign in with your credentials");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call it when I click the function alertCtrl() from a button, from `some.html`.
can any one say where i am doing the mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `app.module`, add the `provider`.

**Note**: `ToastProvider` takes constructor arguments, so we need a `Factory` to create that object. It is part of the `app.module` (last few lines)

Additional Imports:

```
import { ToastProvider } from '../pages/home/toast'
import { ToastController, ToastOptions } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Module definition:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [//no change
  ],
  imports: [//no change
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [//nochange
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, {provide: ToastProvider, useFactory:ToastProviderFactory, deps:[ToastController ] }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
export function ToastProviderFactory(tc) {
  return new ToastProvider(tc, null);
}
```

In Home.ts page (or where you want to use the service/provider), define/inject `ToastProvider` in the constructor:

```
export class SignupPage {

        constructor(toastCtrl: ToastProvider, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad secondPage');
    }


    alertCtrl(){
        this.toastCtrl.buttonToast("Please sign in with your credentials");
    }
}
```

Tested working in Stackblitz..

Comment: this one is also not solved, I gave a try before only. I'm getting this error : 
  `Cannot read property 'buttonToast' of undefined`

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz page?

Comment: heres the URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/import-function-from-another-ts

Comment: Updated the answer. Your provider is accepting parameters, so adding it is slightly different.

Comment: Thanks, @Aragorn. Can  you explain what was the mistake I was doing ? because there are few other things which I need to import. Thanks Man

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain as you can see in the answer, its two steps really: 1. you need to make your service as provider by defining it in the app.module 2. Inject that service into a component through the constructor. Only wrinkle in your case is that step no.1 is not straight forward as the service constructor takes parameters. But that is solved through a factory in app.module.ts.

Answer (score 3):

Inject the `ToastProvider` to your component. Also make sure the `ToastProvider` is registered in list of Providers `providers: []` for the `AppModule` or the module where it is used. 
In angular 7, you can also create your **Injectable services** and make them available in root using:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

And use it in the constructor:

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public toastProvider: ToastProvider ) { }
```

Now access it using `this.toastProvider`

```
alertCtrl(){
        this.toastProvider.buttonToast("Please sign in with your credentials");
    }
```

Comment: I did this before only, I was getting this error: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SignupPage -> ToastProvider]: 
`

Comment: This is known as dependency injection and more info can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain: updated answer to add the providers to app

Comment: `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})` 
where should I inject this ?

Comment: It should be in your service.: 
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ToastProvider {`